# Setting video path before initializing video controller

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, video, dart

So, I'm trying to use flutter's example to test a video, but I want to provide a file path that is saved in the persistent storage. My problem is that I can't wrap my head around on how to do that.

Here's my code: https://dartpad.dev/6930fc8c208c9bd1c00ae34303365e48

```
Future<String> getVideo() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var videoid = prefs.getString('fileview');
    return videoid;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getVideo();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(getVideo()));
    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
  }
  }
```

So I can't set getVideo() to File because it's a future in initstate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write another async function for initialising your controller and listen that future for building your UI.

```
Future initPlayer() async {
   var filePath = await getVideo();
   _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(filePath));
   _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
   _controller.setLooping(true);
   return _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
}
```

You have to write another function to handle the playing state, because the player will be null when the build method will run for the first time.

```
bool get isVideoPlaying {
   return _controller?.value?.isPlaying != null && _controller.value.isPlaying;
}
```

Finally, modify your build method like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Butterfly Video'),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: initPlayer(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          if (isVideoPlaying) {
            _controller?.pause();
          } else {
            _controller?.play();
          }
        });
      },
      child: Icon(
        isVideoPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```